# Traveling to the UK with a German travel document

Tags: visas

My sister-in-law has a German blue passport. Does she need a visa to come to the UK?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are either referring to a "September 28th 1954 Convention" Travel Document for Stateless or "July 28th 1951 Convention" Travel Document for Refugees. These are the only German passport like documents which are blue in color.

[image: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reiseausweis_f%C3%BCr_Staatenlose#/media/File:Reiseausweis_D_aussen.jpg]

The UK are not part of Schengen, thus implementing their own immigration policies. A quick look on gov.uk tells you, that unless your sister-in-law holds an Article 10 residence permit ("Residence Card of a Family Member of a Union Citizen") or is being sponsored by her partner or other family member, she is required to obtain visa to enter the UK for tourism. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwxEZ.jpg)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwxEZ.jpg) https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/stateless-or-refugee/tourism